# PHP Laravel : Couldn't track device name using antonioribeiro/tracker

Tags: php, laravel, tracker

I want to track the device name of the user have used for accessing the site. for that I'm using [antonioribeiro/tracker](https://github.com/antonioribeiro/tracker) But while accessing the device name it's showing

```
 Trying to get property of non-object
```

Here is the controller I have used for that:

```
 public function postUser(Request $request)
    {
        $user=new User();
        $user->name= $request->Input(['name']);
        $user->email=$request->Input(['email']);
        $user = Tracker::currentSession();
        dd($user->device->platform) ;
        //dd( $user->device->is_mobile);
    //  $pageViews = Tracker::pageViews(60 * 24 * 30);
    //  dd($pageViews);
        $user->save();
        return redirect('userPage');
    }
```

How do I resolve my problem. If anyone find the solution please provide a valid one.

Comment: Which statement gives the error?

Comment: `dd($user->device->platform) ; `

Comment: what does `dd($user)` show?